# Tab Bar does not show on View Controller inside Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm running into this issue when I'm opening a new View Controller programmatically.

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "overViewScreen") as! OverviewViewController
controller.user = self.userObject
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The structure of my project : 
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwXaz.png)

On my storyboard the tab bar is shown onto the View Controller (with the table on the right), but when I run the app it looks like this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f51zH.png)

I hope you guys can help me out!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting NavigationController without tab bar controller. You need to present TabBarController.

Give your TabBarController identifier and instantiate them just like you've done with controller

code from comment:

```
let tabVC = UIStoryboard(name: "NameOfYourStoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UITabBarController

let navVc = tabVC.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController

let vc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! OverviewViewController
vc.incorrectAuthorization = SettingsAuthorizationMethod.fingerprint
vc.user = self.userObject

present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")           
                            self.present(tabBarController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Or something like this:
let tabVC = UIStoryboard(name: "NameOfYourStoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UITabBarController

    let navVc = tabVC.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController

    let vc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! LoginViewController
    vc.incorrectAuthorization = SettingsAuthorizationMethod.fingerprint
    vc.user = self.userObject

    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: So now I have : let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UITabBarController
                            let navVc = tabBarController.childViewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
                            
                                let vc = navVc.childViewControllers.first as! OverviewViewController
                            vc.user = self.userObject
                            
                            self.present(navVc, animated: true, completion: nil). Error : Could not cast LoginViewController to UITabBarController

Comment: LoginViewController was my name of class, just change that to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to fix it like this :

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController
                            vc.user = self.userObject
                            let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                            self.present(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I made a seperate controller class "TabBarController", and added a property "user" to this class. In my "OverViewController" I can get the property as follows :

```
let tabBar: TabBarController = tabBarController as! TabBarController
    user = tabBar.user
```

Thanks for the help!